# jQuery syntax problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my simple function and I have

```
<p>This is paragraph 1.</p>
```

like this but this function is not working? What is wrong here?

```
function select(){
    $('p')[0].innerHTML="Helooo!!";
}
```

Comment: Is there only one `<p>` element? Also, could you try `$('p').eq(0).html('test')` to see what happens?

Comment: How are you calling the function? What heppens if you put an `alert('hello')` on the first line fo the func?

Comment: Are you calling `select` somewhere?  Where? When? It works well if called correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/TGSXw/ The function (although you do it in an unusual way) is not the problem.

Comment: +1, use [html](http://docs.jquery.com/Html) instead of innerHTML.

Comment: For people to help you, you'll have to provide a lot more information. "Where are you calling `select`?" for instance, would be the obvious first question. Also, if you're using jQuery anyway, I'd use the `html` function in preference to `innerHTML` since jQuery works around some issues for you, e.g. `$('p:first').html('Hello');`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NbCmq/ You might not be including jQuery. You certainly aren't including much help - are there errors in the error console? Some more context...

Comment: I call my select function like that; I just wantto click on button and appears hello; instead of This is paragraph 1          <input type = "button" value="Select"onclick="select( )">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<p>This is paragraph 1.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 2.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 3.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 4.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 5.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 6.</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('p:eq(0)').html("Helooo!!");
```

I suggest this, because it is easy to change it to apply for more elements, if necessary later.

Comment: @LAmureTJ: This doesn't solve your actual problem, it's only a replacement for the part of your code that already works. If you put that code in your function and try to call it with the code that you have, it still won't work...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the function (well, it works at least), the problem is how you call it.

As you are calling the function from an event in the button element, the code will be executed with the button element as scope. The button element also has a `select` method, so when you are trying to call your `select` function, the method in the element will be called instead.

You can either rename the function to something that doesn't conflict with the methods in the element:

```
<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectClick()">
```

or you can use the `window` object to specify that you want to use your global function instead of the one defined for the element:

```
<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="window.select()">
```

(I would recommend the former option.)

Note that the `innerHTML` property actually is non-standard (until HTML 5), so you should rather use the `html` method in jQuery:

```
function selectClick() {
  $('p:first').html("Helooo!!");
}
```

Or, if you are just putting plain text in the paragraph, the `text` method:

```
function selectClick() {
  $('p:first').text("Helooo!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function select(){
   $('p:first').text("Helooo!!");
}
```

or

```
function select(){
   $('p').eq(0).text("Helooo!!")
}
```

Comment: No, the jQuery object does not have a `.innerHTML` property.

Comment: You find the manipulation API of jQuery here [Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

Comment: @LAmureTJ: No, there is no innerHTML method in the jQuery library: http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=innerhtml